# Regex match a certain format

Tags: regex

I'm really bad at regex (I really can't understand it for the life of me). I want a regex that matches a substring which starts with # (e.g. #something), but is not surrounded by square parenthesis (e.g. [#something]).

So far, I managed to put together a regex that matches a substring between square parenthesis, like this:

```
\[([^\[\]]+)\]
```

Comment: Looks like `(?<!\[)#\w+\b(?!])` can help. Or, `(?<!\[(?=#\w+]))#\w+`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l0Pl7p/1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend your approach by using your pattern and omit the capture group from it. Then that will be the part that you don't want to match.

Add an alternation `|` to the pattern followed by a capture group to match what you do want.

```
\[[^\[\]]+\]|(#[^\s#]+)
```

- `\[[^\[\]]+\]` Match from `[...]`
- `|` Or
- `(#[^\s#]+)` Capture **group 1**, match # and 1+ times any char other than a whitspace char or #

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3gSp7L/1)

Comment: But isn't the op trying _not_ to match those surrounded by square brackets?

Comment: @Gary You get those in the capture group, so you get the ones with the square brackets "out of the way" first.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now.  I wouldn't have thought to do it that way, but it's always good to see different approaches

Comment:  Congratulations on reaching this milestone of 100k! 

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks man! :-) Most of the knowledge gained from all the volunteers here on SO